# Get count for unique terms

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, I want to get unique terms and counts for that terms.

```
index:
doc1: filetype(multivalued): pdf, zip, zip, txt

expected result:
pdf: 1
zip: 2
txt: 1
```

I made this query, but I got an error.

```
"aggs": {
    "uniqueTerms": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "filetype"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "filetype"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make a query to get the result?

index mapping updated:

```
"file" : {
    "properties" : {
        "filetype" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "norms" : {
                "enabled" : false
            },
            "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                      "type" : "string",
                      "index" : "not_analyzed",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good start, you're almost there. You simply need to nest the `cardinality` aggregation one level deeper.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "uniqueTerms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "filetype"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "filetype"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it looks to get document count.I need counts for each unique terms.

Comment: that query makes this result, pdf: 1, zip: 1, txt:1

Comment: that query makes this result, pdf: 3, zip:3, txt: 3, all terms have the same values.

Comment: the result i wanted is only works on nested data type, right?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my index mapping like this:

```
...
"file": {
    "type" : "nested"
}
...
```

"file" is an array and contains file information.

and then, I made this query:

```
"aggs": {
    "1": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "file"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "2": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "file.file_type.raw"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the query worked correctly.